# How to access the describe text in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm writing some specs that test the template files in a gem that has generators for Rails.  I'd love to access to "admin_layout.html.erb" in the rspec spec below:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "admin_layout.html.erb" do

  it "has page title Admin" do
     HERES WHERE I WOULD LOVE TO HAVE ACCESS TO "admin_layout.html.erb" AS A VARIABLE
  end

end
```

Comment: I'm curious, what would this let you do?

Comment: I'm building an admin generator in Rails, and I'm trying to test some basics about the contents of the templates that the generator I'm writing uses

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `self.class.description` to get this info:

```
it "has page title Admin" do
  layout = self.class.description 
  # => "admin_layout.html.erb"
end
```

However, keep in mind this will only put out the first parent's description. So if you have contexts in your `describe` block, then the examples within the contexts would give the context name for `self.class` instead of the `describe` block's name. In that case, you could use metadata:

```
describe "admin_layout.html.erb", :layout => "admin_layout.html.erb"
  context "foo" do
    it "has page title Admin" do
      layout = example.metadata[:layout]
    end
  end
end
```

In case you want the top-level description, you can use `self.class.top_level_description`:

```
RSpec.describe "Foo", type: :model do
  context "bar" do
    it "is part of Foo" do
      self.class.top_level_description
      # => "Foo"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In RSpec 3, use `RSpec.current_example.metadata[...]`. See [this issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1123).

Comment: In RSpec 3, to get the top level description (i.e. "admin_layout.html.erb"), you can use `self.class.top_level_description`.